# sort values with number and character in the same string A1,B1

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I have a df with column values of
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
....

and I want to sort to:
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
...
So sort by the number and then the letter. How should I do that?

Comment: hi, please dont use stackoverflow to simply get answers to your work. Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
column = 3
df[column] = sorted(list(df[column]), key=lambda x: int(x[1:])+ord(x[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not working. I need to sort the values in column 3 and have 5 columns in total.

Comment: Sorry,  i thought you where trying to sort the columns. I've edited the code.

Comment: I changed a bit what you wrote and now it works!

Comment: column = 'Image' df[column] = sorted(list(df[column]), key=lambda x: int(x[1:]) + ord(x[1]))